# Adding LWGEOM to QGIS 3 Processing Toolbox

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

In 2.x versions of QGIS I was able to add LWGEOM to the QGIS Processing Toolbox and run the Make Valid command. Using OSGEO4W, I've downloaded QGIS 3.2.1 and also downloaded the latest LIBLWGEOM, but I can't see a way to add the LWGEOM tools to the Toolbox. Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference: in May 2019 the "Make Valid" tool was [added](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/24017) to the core QGIS 3 Processing toolbox, as "[Fix Geometries](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#fix-geometries)" within the Vector Geometry group.

Answer (score 2):

Because lwgeom is a Python Plugin, it must be installed from inside QGis. Further, since Qgis3 a plugins code must be valid python3 code. At least, each plugin defines which versions of QGis are supported. In the case of lwgeom, latest qgis version is 2.99 (https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/processinglwgeomprovider/version/0.4.4/).
So I recommend to contact the developer of that plugin.